# Where am I going wrong in comparing the dates using my method?

Tags: java, validation, class, date

This is my code :

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 * that checks for the validity of a date 
 */
public class ValidDate {

    /**
     * @param  date //date to be checked passed as arguement
     * @return  z // true or false  
     * // returns true if the date is in correct format else false
     */
    public boolean check(String date) {
        boolean z= true;
        label: // using labelled break technique
        //Exception handling( process of dealing with erroneous situations during program execution) using try-catch
        try {
            for(int i =0; i<9;i++) {
                if(i==0||i==1||i==3||i==4||i==6||i==7||i==8||i==9) { //dd-mm-Yyyy 
                    if(Character.isDigit(date.charAt(i))==false) {
                        z=false;
                        break label;
                    }
                } else if(i==2||i==5) {
                    if(!(date.charAt(i)== '-')) { 
                        z=false;
                        break label;
                    }
                } if(i==8) {
                    if (!(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,5))<=12)) {
                        z=false;
                        break label;
                    }
                    if (!(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2))<=31)) {
                        z=false;
                        break label;
                    }
                    if (!(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6))>=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR))) {
                        z=false;
                    } else {
                        break label ;
                    }
                    if (!(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,5))>=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH))) {
                        z=false;
                    } else {
                        break label ;
                    }

                    if (!(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2))>Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE))) {
                        z=false;
                    } else {
                        break label;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            z=false;
        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

Now if I enter the wrong year(that is less than the current year) as input it returns false but if I give the wrong date (i.e. less than the current date of the same month) or the wrong month(i.e. less than the current month) then it returns true but it should return false. Can someone please help me to debug this code ?

Comment: Can you fix formatting in your question?

Comment: Why are you not converting to a real `Date` object by parsing with a `DateFormat` and doing the comparison between `Date` objects? That would be much simpler.

Comment: @Seth I didn't get you ?

Comment: @Abcd It was a pain in the ass fixing the formatting :P SO doesn't keep the formatting when you copy code, so you should always make sure to fix it before posting your question (:

Comment: @Seth but which word did you desire to use that starts with a C

Comment: @Abcd Forget it, it was sort of rude, sorry :)

Comment: @Seth its ok brother :)

Comment: no answer anyone ?

Comment: Looking randomly, the `for` will never execute for `9` and you do check if `i==9`.

Comment: @Abcd Jim Garrison already asked, but I am curious too: Why not just parse to a `Date` object and use `Date` compare? What do you want to do with this method?

Comment: @ModusTollens because i want to try this method and I am a tenth grader so I am trying to boost my coding skills

Comment: @Abcd to get out od yourbquestion ban, i would suggest editing this question. When you edit, you give your question some more visibility. If your bad questions get reopened/upvoted, you should be out of the ban.

Comment: @abcd for this particular question, read the banner. You need a minimal example to reproduce. Your code here seems a bit too verbose. Also.... You seem to be using stack as a "ask anything" site. That's the best way to get tereible reception:/

Comment: @GhostCat I didn't get you. Has the ban been lifted from me?

Comment: I reminded you to look into accepting an answer. You did so. That is all. I don't know about any bans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe below is what you want.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ValidDate {
    /**
     * @param date
     *            //date to be checked passed as arguement
     * @return z // true or false // returns true if the date is in correct
     *         format else false
     */
    public static boolean check(String date) {
        boolean z = true;
        //no need to use label
        //label: // using labelled break technique
        // Exception handling( process of dealing with erroneous situations
        // during program execution) using try-catch
        try {
            //< 10, not < 9
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 7 || i == 8 || i == 9)// dd-mm-Yyyy
                {
                    if (Character.isDigit(date.charAt(i)) == false) {
                        z = false;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (i == 2 || i == 5) {
                    if (!(date.charAt(i) == '-')) {
                        z = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //not 8
                if (i == 9) {
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5)) > 12)) {
                        z = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2)) > 31)) {
                        z = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("YEAR:" + (Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6)) + " " + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)));
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6)) < Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR))) {
                        z = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("MONTH:" + (Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5)) + " " + (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)));
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3, 5)) < (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1))) {
                        z = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("DATE:" + (Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2)) + " " + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE)));
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2)) < Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE))) {
                        z = false;
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            z = false;
        }
        return z;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(check("02-05-2016"));
    }
}
```

Comment: are those the only two mistakes -- not 8 and not 10